Can't Upload PDF - XAMPP using PHP (MAC)
I am trying to upload pdf's (cv's). I am not sure why I can't, but for some reason the pdf's won't upload.
I am new to PHP and HTML, so if you have any security tips for file uploads, that would be nice too. Here is my code:
php code
// Handle file upload
$uploaddir = '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/upload/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name']);
if(!file_exists($uploadfile))
    mkdir($uploaddir, 775);

try {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.";
    else
        throw new Exception($_FILES['cv']['error']);
    } 
catch (Exception $e) {
    die("Couldn't upload file: ". $e->getMessage());
}

html code
<input type="file" name="cv" id="cv" placeholder="Upload CV" required>
<button type="submit">Register</button>

SOLUTION
I made a folder in the temp folder that I then moved the uploaded file to. That ended up working.

using chmod 775 on directory in case it was a permissions issue
checked file max size on php.ini; nothing wrong with the size of my file
getting errors to analyze, but no known errors are thrown, just that it hasn't uploaded


It is far betterto check the $_FILES['cv']['error'] BEFORE doing anything else. The error will always mean upload failed, it just tells you the reason, you can then code accordingly

(1) make sure you have enctype= multipart/form-data in your form tag (2) There is no point to execute mkdir($uploaddir, 775); everytime you trigger the upload script, you should create this upload directory and set the permission by say SSH / FTP just ONCE

None of those have worked, unfortunately. And, the ['error'] is giving me code 0, but I have no idea why the file is not showing up in the folder.

(1) Change $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name']); to $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $_FILES['cv']['name'];  (2) Make sure $uploaddir (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/upload/) is writable by the system

The folder is writable by the system. I ensured that just now. I made the above changes. Still not uploading the file, though. It's annoying though because there aren't any errors being thrown by ['error'] anymore, it is just failing to upload. It doesn't make any sense. Could this just be a Mac problem?
